# ¿SQL case puede devolver una condición?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un dilema con una consulta de `SQL server 2014`

tengo mi tabla departamentos, personal y cargos. Entonces según el departamento debo obtener x cargo

la consulta que tengo es esta:

```
SELECT * from  departamentos, personal, cargos
where 
CASE 
WHEN departamento in (2,3,4,11,12) THEN cargo in (1,3)
WHEN departamento in (9,10,13,14,15) THEN cargo in (2,4)
ELSE cargo in (5,7)
END
```

investigue un poco en internet y si puedo hacer la consulta al ejecutarla en https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_case
con el siguiente código:

```
SELECT * from  OrderDetails o
where OrderDetailID > 200 
and 
CASE 
WHEN ProductID in ( 2, 3) THEN o.Quantity in (1, 25)
WHEN ProductID in ( 1000) THEN o.Quantity in (15, 65)
ELSE o.Quantity > 150
END
order by ProductID
```

En la página obtiene el resultado, pero al ejecutarla en mi SQL no funciona y me arroja el siguiente error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.(42000,156) Procedure(SP_GetDatos)
```

** la consulta que ejecuté en w3 me retorna los siguientes datos
-Cantidad total de datos en la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Datos retornados luego de la consulta
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que, el `case` en cada `then` retorna una condición diferente en base al departamento que se obtenga

sí alguien puede orientarme o señalarme en que estoy fallando, agradezco de antemano

Comment: Tu código no se entiende, ¿qué debería devolver cada `CASE`, por ejemplo si esto se cumple: `departamento in (2,3,4,11,12)` qué debe ocurrir?

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye datos de ejemplo que puedan utilizarse. También un ejemplo de la salida esperada.

Comment: Este sql es muy raro.. para que base de datos?

Comment: en la página w3schools el case retorna una "condición" y al ejecutar la consulta debajo del link, esta funciona

Comment: Explica a qué te refieres con que *el case retorna una condición* ¿? [Si lees la doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) verás que `CASE` devuelve un resultado o un grupo de resultados, no una condición. Explica qué es lo que quieres lograr, parece que estás intentando un código no estándar o tomando el camino largo para resolver un problema sencillo. Lo digo porque el código y el planteamiento son extraños y no se explica con claridad el problema.

Comment: vuelvo a preguntar.. en que base de datos?? supongo que al ser algo muy particular, no va a funcionar en cualquier motor.. igual es raro lo que pedis.. no necesitas un case para eso.. con un or alcanza...

Comment: @gbianchi según el mensaje de error en la pregunta es SQL Server.

Comment: ah ahi lo vi gracias @A.Cedano.. fijate que su case son 3 condiciones unidas por OR y AND en el medio...

Comment: Sql server 2014 y si es poco convencional el código jajaja, de que manera lo puedo simplificar utilizando el `or`, ya que dependiendo el departamento es el cargo que debo buscar

Comment: When (departamento in (2,3,4,11,12) and cargo in (1,3)) OR 
        (departamento in (9,10,13,14,15) and cargo in (2,4))
        OR cargo in (5,7) proba si no es lo mismo

Answer (score 1):

Para responder la pregunta principal, una expresión `CASE` no puede devolver un valor booleano que sea usado directamente por la clausula `WHERE`. Sin embargo, no es necesario utilizar un CASE y solamente necesitas trabajar con operadores lógicos.

Para el ejemplo, voy a utilizar la segunda consulta que compartes porque la primera tiene 3 tablas y no hay criterios para unirlas que pueda utilizar. Si te fijas, solo voy agrupando las condiciones para generar un solo resultado booleano al evaluar todas las condiciones unidas por `AND` y `OR`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  OrderDetails o
WHERE OrderDetailID > 200 
AND (  ( o.ProductID in ( 2, 3) AND o.Quantity in (1, 25))
    OR ( o.ProductID in ( 1000) AND o.Quantity in (15, 65))
    OR o.Quantity > 150)
ORDER BY ProductID;
```

Comment: No entendi porque no usaste la original, cuando puse en comentarios como deberia ser la original ;)

Comment: la respuesta de @gbianchi estaba cerca, tuve que cambiar el `when` por un `and` y en el ultimo `OR` agregarle un `not in` de todos los departamentos antes mencionados, por que me juntaba personal que no debía aparecer

Comment: @gbianchi Podía cambiar la condición de la original, pero la consulta usa 3 tablas sin condiciones explícitas para unirlas. Por integridad, prefiero no publicar código con fallas que haya identificado previamente.